How to find a list of all SEC’s Exemptive Relief & No-Action Letters in investment management, and the conditions that grants such SEC exceptions?
I understand that “Exemptive Relief” and “No-Action Letters” from provisions of the Investment Company Act allows certain funds to deviate from standard regulatory requirements, typically to accommodate innovative investment strategies or unique fund structures.
These exemptions are granted by the SEC under specific conditions and are thoroughly scrutinized to ensure they align with public interest and do not compromise investor protections. Such exemptions are often requested when funds aim to introduce performance fees or offer non-transparent fund structures that might otherwise be restricted by the Act.
Where can we find a list of them for investment management, and more importantly, the conditions that might lead to such SEC exceptions?

https://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/cfnew/cf-noaction.shtml  As for "the conditions that might lead to such SEC exceptions" I think you'd need an entire law firm's expertise to answer that.

Thanks for sharing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
